# AnimationDrawable in GetView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I have developed the `ListView` which has one `TextView` and two `ImageView`s. I have set `AnimationDrawable` for each ImageView. My problem is animation starts again when I am scrolling down and then to top. I have set 5 images to the frame. For example if ImageView showing 3rd image, i am scrollong down and then to top. Now ImageView showing first image which means animation starts again. I want to keep the animation after scrolling also.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
     if (vi == null) {
            vi = adapterInflater.inflate(R.layout.categoryadapter, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.lPic = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.rPic = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            holder.category = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_category);
            vi.setTag(holder);
     }
     else
     {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
     }
     fontStyle = Typeface.createFromAsset(adapterActivity.getAssets(),
                "fonts/Helvetica.TTF");


    final Categary assingValue = list.get(position);
    holder.category.setTypeface(fontStyle);
    holder.category.setText(assingValue.desc);

    leftImage=assingValue.leftPicture;
    rightImage=assingValue.rightPicture;

    AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    for (String image : leftImage) {
           ImageLoader obj=new ImageLoader(adapterActivity);    
           holder.lPic.setTag(image);
           Bitmap b=obj.getBitmap(image, holder.lPic);
           Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(adapterActivity.getResources(),b);          
           animation.addFrame(d, 15 * 1000);
    }
    holder.lPic.setImageDrawable(animation);
    animation.setOneShot(false);


    AnimationDrawable animation1 = new AnimationDrawable();
    for (String image : rightImage) {

           ImageLoader obj=new ImageLoader(adapterActivity);    
           holder.rPic.setTag(image);
           Bitmap b=obj.getBitmap(image, holder.rPic);
           Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(adapterActivity.getResources(),b);
           animation1.addFrame(d, 15 * 1000);
    }
    holder.rPic.setImageDrawable(animation1);
    animation1.setOneShot(false);

    animation.start();
    animation1.start();     

    return vi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

Create all your views in constructor of the adapter and store in a list then in get view just return that view.

for ex:

```
@Override
public View createView(final int position) {

    View vi = null;
    ViewHolder holder;

    vi = adapterInflater.inflate(R.layout.categoryadapter, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.lPic = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    holder.rPic = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    holder.category = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_category);
    fontStyle = Typeface.createFromAsset(adapterActivity.getAssets(),
                "fonts/Helvetica.TTF");
    final Categary assingValue = list.get(position);
    holder.category.setTypeface(fontStyle);
    holder.category.setText(assingValue.desc);

    leftImage=assingValue.leftPicture;
    rightImage=assingValue.rightPicture;

    AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    for (String image : leftImage) {
           ImageLoader obj=new ImageLoader(adapterActivity);    
           holder.lPic.setTag(image);
           Bitmap b=obj.getBitmap(image, holder.lPic);
           Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(adapterActivity.getResources(),b);          
           animation.addFrame(d, 15 * 1000);
    }
    holder.lPic.setImageDrawable(animation);
    animation.setOneShot(false);
    AnimationDrawable animation1 = new AnimationDrawable();
    for (String image : rightImage) {

           ImageLoader obj=new ImageLoader(adapterActivity);    
           holder.rPic.setTag(image);
           Bitmap b=obj.getBitmap(image, holder.rPic);
           Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(adapterActivity.getResources(),b);
           animation1.addFrame(d, 15 * 1000);
    }
    holder.rPic.setImageDrawable(animation1);
    animation1.setOneShot(false);
    animation.start();
    animation1.start();     
    return vi;
}
```

Call above function for each item and store returned view in a list of views:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return views.get(position);
}
```

I have not tried it but this might work.

Let me know what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer brother. I done this by using dynamic tablerows